# Calculating number of possible combinations

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, combinations

I am building a web application which allows users to pick an importance weight for a number of parameters.Those weights are fed into a script with an algorithm that produces a raster output.

There are 6 parameters, and 3 possible weights each (low, med, high, which translate to numerical multipliers in the script).

We are considering pre-running the script for each possible parameter/weight combination, but need to get a sense of how many that will be. I know I used to solve this problem in high school math, but my memory is failing me.

So with my 6 parameters and 3 weights possible for each, how many total rasters would I need to generate to have all possibilities covered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $6$ parameters with $3$ choices for each. This gives a total of $3^6=729$ different possible states.

Think about it this way: For the first parameter you have three options. For each of these options, you can choose one of three options for the second parameter as well. This gives $3\times 3$ options for these two combined. But for each of these (nine) options, you can choose one of three options for the third parameter, and so on.